# Spring task executor only creates one instance when the @Scheduled annotation is placed inside of polling class

Tags: java, spring, task

I have a series of services that extend a base service. In this base service I instantiate a class designed to poll databases and send notifications based on their contents, the timing of this polling is handled by spring. What I expect is that there should be an instance of this poller for each service extending the base service, but depending on where I put the @Scheduled annotation, it doesn't work.

What I want is this:

```
public class Base {
    private Poller p = new Poller(this);

    // the rest of the service code
}

public class Poller{

    Base b;

    public Poller(Base B){
        b=B;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void poll(){
        //do stuff
        System.out.println(b.name); //doesn't work, causes really unhelpful errors
        System.out.println("----"); //prints as expected, but only once
                                    //regardless of how many extending services exist
    }
}
```

but it only seems to instantiate one poller between all extenders. If I Structure it like this:

```
public class Base {
    private Poller p = new Poller(this);

    // the rest of the service code

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void poll(){
        p.poll();
    }
}

public class Poller{

    Base b;

    public Poller(Base B){
        b=B;
    }

    public void poll(){
        //do stuff
        System.out.println(b.name); //prints the name of the service for each extender
        System.out.println("----"); //prints as expected, once for each extender
    }
}
```

it works as expected, but doesn't sit well with the design goals here.

Is there a way to get the scheduled annotation to stay in the Poller, while ensuring that each extending service gets its own instance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `Poller` class isn't Spring managed, where `Base` is.  `Poller` is instantiated with the `new` operator in `Base`, and therefore, Spring has no handle on it.  If Spring isn't creating the instance, then it is not going to be Spring managed.

I think your design in general is flawed though.  Your child has a reference to the base and the base to the child.  To me, it seems like you may have a hard time creating multiple child classes this way.

If you want to have a base class, I would recommend one of two things.

1. Inheritance.  Have `Poller` (as well as other child classes) extend `Base`.
2. Delegation.  Have `Base` be a member of each child class, and delegate to it in the children classes.

With either one of these designs, I think you could get your code to work as you expect.